# WHat is the cause of "GatewayTimeout" when deploying ARM Templates?

Tags: azure-resource-manager

I'm re-deploying an ARM template.

Whereas it worked last night (...) it's failing with:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "GatewayTimeout",
    "message": "The gateway did not receive a response from 'Microsoft.Maps' within the specified time period."
  }
}
```

This in turn causes the deployment to hang (for an hour+).

I'm *pretty sure* (but not 100%) that I didn't do a change that would cause this -- is this a Microsoft infrastructure problem?

If so, is there an url on Microsoft that provides information as to the status of services, and ETA as to when it would come back online?

If not, any way of getting more verbose error status report to ferret out the underlying cause (by me?). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out to be on the Azure Management API side of things, offline for a half day. The service remained up, but management/deployment apis down for a bit.